# How to set onclick listener on inflater code

Tags: java, android, json

I have a java code as HomeBaseAdapter.java As a additional feature I have to enable a onclick listener as well as other functionalities of java class like image slider etc:

Here in Case:1 the article layout is being coded. Here i want image slider to be displayed with an onclick listener for the images

### HomeBaseAdapter.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

class HomeBaseAdapter {

    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private String[] heading = new String[]{"Business Directory", "Articles", "Gallery", "Institutes", "Bus Routes", "Property Listing", "Traffic Live News", "Events"};
    private Set<String> firstSet;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    HomeBaseAdapter(AppCompatActivity a) throws JSONException {
        activity = a;
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity).getString("theJson", ""));
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ListView listView = (ListView)a.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter2());
        SharedPreferences listpref = a.getSharedPreferences("list", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> set = listpref.getStringSet("DATE_LIST", null);
        list.addAll(set);
        firstSet = new HashSet<>(list);
        Set<String> secondSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(heading));
        firstSet.retainAll(secondSet);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView heading;
        TextView bannerView;
        ImageView img;
        Button more;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
    }

    public class BaseAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "SetTextI18n"})
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_home_items, null);
                holder.img =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                holder.heading =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
                holder.more =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.more);
                holder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.l1);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.heading.setText(list.get(position));
            holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (list.get(position) == "Articles") {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Article.class));
                    } else if (list.get(position) == "Business Directory") {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, BusinessDirectory.class));
                    } else if (list.get(position) == "Gallery") {
                        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, Gallery1.class));
                    }

                }
            });
                holder.linearLayout.addView(rowItems(position));
                Toast.makeText(activity, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("position",""+position);
            return convertView;
            }

        }

        View rowItems(int position) {
            try {
                String json = jsonObject.getString(list.get(position));
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
                Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    if (!key.equals("")) {
                        JSONObject innerJObject = jObject.getJSONObject(key);
                       switch (Arrays.asList(heading).indexOf(list.get(position))) {
                            case 0: {
                                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_home, null);
                                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                                TextView address1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress1);
                                TextView area =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewArea);
                                TextView pincode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPinCode);
                                TextView phno =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneNumber);

                                title.setText(innerJObject.getString("ShopTitle"));
                                address1.setText(innerJObject.getString("Address1"));
                                area.setText(innerJObject.getString("Area"));
                                pincode.setText("Chennai-" + innerJObject.getString("PinCode"));
                                phno.setText(innerJObject.getString("PhoneNumber"));
                                return view;
                            }
                             case 1: {
                            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_home_image, null);
                            TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                            TextView desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
                            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                            Picasso.with(activity).load("http://www.northmadras.com/upload/Articles/" + innerJObject.getString("Image")).resize(400, 400).into(img);
                            title.setText(innerJObject.getString("Title"));
                            desc.setText(innerJObject.getString("Prelode"));
                            return view;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

Here are the two classes that i am using for displaying the images in the image slider

The article.java which use the custom class which is MyCustomPageradapter.java

### Article.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Article extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    static SimpleAdapter adapter;
    static int startIndex;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList;
   //int images[] = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, R.drawable.image_4};
    MyCustomPagerAdapter myCustomPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.article);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        new Article.json(startIndex).execute();
        startIndex+=10;
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        Toast.makeText(Article.this, ""+position+"--"+positionOffset+"--"+positionOffsetPixels, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});

}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class json extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>{

        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        int startIndex;
        public json(int startIndex) {
            this.startIndex=startIndex;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Article.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            arrayList.addAll(userFunction.getArticle(startIndex));
            try
            {
                Log.e("aaa",arrayList.toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            return arrayList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayList) {
            try {
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(Article.this, arrayList);
                viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("err",e+"error 1234567890");


            } pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }
  }
```

---

### MyCustomPagerAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyCustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> images;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyCustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        //imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.northmadras.com/upload/Articles/"+images.get(position).get(0)).into(imageView);
        textView.setText(images.get(position).get(1));
        Log.e("img","http://www.northmadras.com/upload/Articles/"+images.get(position).get(1));
        container.addView(itemView);

        //listening to image click
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ArticleContent.class));
            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: i would say make your own interface for `onClick` and implement it with `ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: As a beginner i have no idea how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interface `CustomItemClickListener`

```
public interface CustomItemClickListener {

   public void onItemClick(View v, int position, int id);

   public void onItemLongClick(View v, int position, int id);
}
```

and then in `viewPagerAdapter` contructor

```
CustomItemClickListener listener;  
...........
public MyCustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> images ,  CustomItemClickListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.listener = listener;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

and then use as

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(v, myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), marqueesLists.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMarqueeId());
    }
});

itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemLongClick(v , myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition() ,marqueesLists.get(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMarqueeId());
        return true;
    }
});
```

and then in your `Activity`

```
myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(Article.this, arrayList,new CustomItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position , int id) {

       //do your `onClick` work here
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View v, int position , int id) {

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Do change the values as per your requirements

Answer (score -1):

implement your class with `View.onClickListener` and override a method `onClick` . 
In that (overriden) `onClick` method you can handle your clicking events stuff.

Comment: can you please explain the usage of getMarqueeId(). And also suggest me how to declare it correctly